# Azure Devops and uploading a Python package to Artifacts using pipeline | authentication issue

Tags: python, azure-devops, artifact, twine

I am trying to use the Azure pipeline to publish a Python package to Artifact's feed.
I could do it from my local machine and upload the package using Twine, but I have an authentication issue in the pipeline.

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-22.04
variables:
  pip_cache_dir: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.pip_cache'

steps:
- task: UsePythonVersion@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '3.10'
    addToPath: true

- bash: |
    python -m venv worker_venv
    source worker_venv/bin/activate
    pip install --upgrade pip
    pip install pipenv
    pipenv requirements > requirements.txt
    pipenv requirements --dev > requirements-dev.txt
    pip install --cache-dir $(pip_cache_dir) -r ./requirements.txt
    pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" --cache-dir $(pip_cache_dir) -r ./requirements.txt
  displayName: 'Install tools'

- script: |
    source worker_venv/bin/activate
    python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
  displayName: 'Build package'

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: sample-feed-01

- script: |
    source worker_venv/bin/activate
    python -m twine upload --verbose --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) --repository-url https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**company**/Platform/_packaging/sample-feed-01/pypi/upload/ dist/*
  env:
    TWINE_USERNAME: "azure"
    TWINE_PASSWORD: $(PYPI_TOKEN)
  displayName: 'Upload package to Azure Artifacts'
```

I tried everything, including GPT-4, but the solutions seem wrong or outdated.
this is the error:

```
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/75d0c60b-0c2a-44e9-be0f-29d838a3b86e.sh
Uploading distributions to 
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**company**/Platform/_packaging/sample-feed-01/pypi/up
load/
INFO     dist/**package**.whl (2.6 KB)                 
INFO     dist/**package**.tar.gz (2.6 KB)                           
INFO     username set by command options                                        
INFO     password set by command options                                        
INFO     username: azure                                                        
INFO     password: <hidden>                                                     
Uploading **package**.whl
25l
  0% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 0.0/5.7 kB • --:-- • ?
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.7/5.7 kB • 00:00 • ?
100% ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.7/5.7 kB • 00:00 • ?
25hINFO     Response from                                                          
         https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**company**/Platform/_packaging/sample-feed-0
         1/pypi/upload/:                                                        
         401 Unauthorized                                                       
INFO     ﻿{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF400813: The user        
         'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this
         resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.Unauth
         orizedRequestException,                                                
         Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedReque
         stException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}                             
ERROR    HTTPError: 401 Unauthorized from                                       
         https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/**company**/Platform/_packaging/sample-feed-0
         1/pypi/upload/                                                         
         Unauthorized
```

I have some doubts about `'aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa'` as user name, which I did not obfuscate, and that is what I see in the pipeline.
any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go the Azure Artifacts feed you want to publish the Python package to, then navigate to **Feed Settings** > **Permissions** page to check and ensure the following identities have been assigned with **`Contributor`** role at least.

- **`Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`**
- **`{ProjectName} Build Service ({OrgName})`**

[image]

For more details, see "[**Job access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---

After configuring the permission role, in the pipeline, you can build and publish the Python package like as below.

```yaml
steps:
- Some steps to install dependences and build the package.

- task: TwineAuthenticate@1
  displayName: 'Twine Authenticate '
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: {feed_name}

- bash: 'twine upload -r {feed_name} --config-file "$(PYPIRC_PATH)" dist/*.whl'
  displayName: 'Publish to Artifacts feed'
```

With this way, you do not need to provide your PAT/password to authenticate.

For more details, see "[**Publish Python packages with Azure Pipelines**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pypi?bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fartifacts%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---

**EDIT:**

By default, the pipeline will use one of the following build identities (also as mentioned above) to access the Azure Artifacts feeds and other resources within current organization:

- **`Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`**: Can access resources with full/partial permissions across projects within current organization by default.
- **`{ProjectName} Build Service ({OrgName})`**: Can access resources with full/partial permissions only within the current project by default.

On the **Organization Settings** (and **Project Settings**), there are two options:

- **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipelines`**
- **`Limit job authorization scope to current project for release pipelines`**

[image]

If the options are enabled, the pipelines use the identity "**`{ProjectName} Build Service ({OrgName})`**". If the options are disabled, the identity "**`Project Collection Build Service ({OrgName})`**" is used.

The **`TwineAuthenticate@1`** task will use one of above build identities to generate the twine credentials and set the credentials to the environment variable **`PYPIRC_PATH`**.

Since the identities might not have the full access to the feed by default, to assign the required permission role to the identities, you need to click the "**`Add users/groups`**" button, then on the pop-up window, search for and add the identities with the required roles.

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you, I cannot see any "build service", I only have a few "build administrator".

Comment: @prhmma, As my above image is showing, you can click the "**Add users/groups**" button, then on the pop-up window to search and add the identities with the required roles.

Comment: yes, I've added a few permissions before, but it seems like build service is not an option for me.

Comment: @prhmma, I have updated my above answer with more information (see **EDIT**). Check and try it.

Comment: Thank you, I already marked your answer as it took me a step forward, but now I have a different issue. first it asks me to login manually `    To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code XXXXXXX to authenticate.`
and then Error getting username from keyring

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `publishArtifact` job from Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-build-artifacts-v1?view=azure-pipelines.

We do this with Poetry. Therefore you need Azure's `TwineAuthenticate` step: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/twine-authenticate-v1?view=azure-pipelines. It will look something like this:

```
jobs:
- job: publishArtifact
  displayName: 'Publish package to Artifacts feed'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: 'Determine Python version'
    inputs:
      versionSpec: <python version>
      architecture: 'x64'

  steps:
  - task: TwineAuthenticate@1
    displayName: "Twine Authenticate to artifact feed"
    inputs:
      artifactFeed: <feed>

  - script: |
      python3 -m pip install poetry==1.5.1
      python -m pip install twine
      poetry build
      python -m twine upload -r <feed>
    displayName: 'Build and publish package with Poetry'
```